# Cordova Android: Open a SQLite .db database from an arbitrary directory

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cordova

I have a Cordova mobile app and I let the user import a SQLite dababase from an external .db file. I'm using the cordova-sqlite-storage

https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage

A naive solution is already implemented but it's risky. Basically the user selects an external .db file using a file picker which replaces the old .db file

```
window.plugins.sqlDB.copyDbFromStorage("mydb.db", 0, file, true, onSuccess);
```

where `file` is the uri of the new .db file.

It works but I'd like to check the .db file first, at least those two checks:

- check if the .db file is actually a SQLite database
- check if the new    SQLite database has some table that must be there
  before importing

**What I've tried**

I tried to find a way to open the .db file from its original directory but it seems that the `openDatabase()` only opens databases stored in the special `default` location (which is, I guess, the internal private storage for the app)

```
openDatabase({name: 'test.db', location: 'default'});
```

other values for the `location` parameter are simply discouraged, they suggest to stick with `default`

Comment: Try to open it; try to read the table.

Comment: @CL I tried but if you look closely you can only call the open database like this: openDatabase({name: 'test.db', location: 'default'}); It doesn't let you specify a path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot (or do not want to) open the database at the original location, then you have to copy it to the internal private storage location with a different file name. (You can then later copy over the old file, or delete and rename the files.)

Comment: thanks for your reply.. and that's what I'm doing actually... but I think it would be simpler to just open the .db file at the original location. From the documentation of Cordova-sqlite-storage it seems there's no way. What I am missing here?

Comment: The documentation mentions that it "supports arbitrary database location on Android".

Comment: I know.. but it doesn't show any example or any other clue about it. The openDatabase function accepts a name (string) and a location which I have no idea what it is supposed to store apart from "default". How can a documentation be so messy and imprecise? could you please tell me how to specify a custom path?

Comment: Use the source, Luke! `dblocations = ["docs", "libs", "nosync"];`

Comment: eheh thank you! but unfortunately I still not follow you :-(. I quote the docs:"The new location option is used to select the database subdirectory location (iOS only) with the following choices:

0 (default): Documents 
1: Library 
2: Library/LocalDatabase" I do not see any place where to pass the absolute path of the external .db file

Comment: There is none .

Comment: I wanted to do the same thing, i.e. open the database from the original location (applicationDirectory). Didn't find a way to do that without copying it to the internal storage location. 
@CL. You mentioned that we can later delete the original file. When I tried, it didn't allow me to delete the original file. Do you know how we can do it?

Comment: @ManojShrestha Do ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.